# display user input value

Tags: php

```
+-----+-------+--------+
  ID  | Owner | Number |
+-----+-------+--------+
 com1 | peter | 103045 |
+-----+-------+--------+
 com2 | deter | 103864 |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

Hey guys. I am working on this part of the project where the user is suppose to input a certain ID. When he input this certain ID it is suppose to print out everything in the row w that ID. In this case if he inputs com1, it will display:

```
+-----+-------+--------+
  ID  | Owner | Number |
+-----+-------+--------+
 com1 | peter | 103045 |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

I used this form and code:

form.php

```
    <form action="query.php" method="POST">
    Enter your ID: <input type="varchar" name="id" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Audit" />
    </form>
```

query.php

```
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    mysql_select_db("livemigrationauditingdb", $con);


    $input = (int) $_POST['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system_audit WHERE ID = $input");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    </tr>";


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Owner'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Number'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close($con);
```

think you guys know the mistake? oh and is there away for me not to link it to other page? i need the form and codes to be in one page. currently my form links to query.php. is there a way to cancel this line and it still works. thanks!

Comment: use $input = $_POST['id'] as Rohan Sood suggests, when casting to an integer and there are characters in the string, the characters will be left out, therefor no ID will match com1 because it will result in just 0 when casting to an integer.

Comment: Put $input in single quotations like: "SELECT * FROM system_audit WHERE ID = '$input' "

Comment: hi siamak and dbf. thank you but i have tried both before. it returns the following message and shows no result

Warning:mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\query.php

Comment: @user1629618 this error happens when it's something wrong with the query string or mysql connection or database selection. make sure that you connected to mysql and select table before the query string and then check the table name "system_audi" and the col name "ID".

Comment: @user1629618 - try echoing out your generated query and entering it directly in the database.

Comment: okay guys. i did all the method. didnt work too :/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the (int) from $input = (int) $_POST['id'];

Comment: Please tell us the result for a print_r($row);

Comment: echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Setting'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Value'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Actual'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

is just to put them in table form

Comment: I got that bro. Just in your document, query.php, put in a "print_r($row)" right after the opening braces for the while statement. And tell us the output.

Comment: OH! pardon me. i havent slept properly for a few days. and nah. it didnt work. says there's a systax error

Comment: What is your result for <?php echo "SELECT * FROM system_audit WHERE ID = $input";?>

Comment: right now it returns the whole table. it does not filter the user input

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

and replace it by

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
```

Also remove the (int) and see if it helps.

```
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Owner'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Number'] . "</td>";
```

Can be replaced by

```
  echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
```

You can also have both of them on the same page as shown

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    mysql_select_db("livemigrationauditingdb", $con);


    $input = (int) $_POST['id'];

    if($input)
    {
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system_audit WHERE ID = $input");

      echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      </tr>";


      while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))
      {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    }

    mysql_close($con); 
?>   

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    Enter your ID: <input type="varchar" name="id" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Audit" />
    </form>

?>
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_row is generally considered as a relatively better practice due to the increased readability of the code. So I wouldn't really recommend your approach, even though it might just get the work done.

Comment: hey again rohan. mm. you said to replace $query to $result. mm, the thing is i did not declare any $result